# What's the best way to separate operator and number in c

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I try build the program that can calculate the number by stack
but I have some stuck.
let's see my program work first

Get an expression example (1+2)*3

Separate and re-arrange it to "1 2 + 3 *"

Get them to this function I will it to be psudocode .

```
 if token is a number
   push onto the stack
 else if token is an operator
   pop operand 1 off the stack
   pop operand 2 off the stack
 apply the operator
 push the result back onto the stack
```

I want the suggestion about how to check the string "1 2 + 3 *"
what is the best way to do this

Sorry about my english

Thanks.

Comment: By check the string you mean what, exactly?  If the question is "how do I tell whether a character is a number, operator, or a space" the answer is `isdigit` and `isspace`.

Comment: I think you already puts spaces b/t two numbers because in postfix notation two(or more operands) can come consecutively as `AB+` so how should interpreter `12`  (`1`, `2`) or `12` so do you add spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to evaluate a postfix expression.

1. Use a char array to get the postfix expression
2. Check for operator, if it is not an operator u can then it must be
       an integer.
3. You can easily convert a character integer to integer by using

> ```
> char x = 9; //Character '9' = ASCII 57
> int b;
>
> b = x - '0'; //That is '9' - '0' = 57 - 48 = 9
> .
> ```

4  And you can simply do the necessary operation on the integer.